# ReferenceError: scForm is not defined in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, teamcity, octopus-deploy, sitecore8, octopack

I get this javascript-error in *Sitecore 8 > Control Panel* when e.g. clicking "Install a package" or any other link:

```
ReferenceError: scForm is not defined
```

Looking in Firebug, seems like a file is missing: http://my.site/-/speak/v1/assets/main.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out: this error occurs, because the file `App_Config/Include/.Sitecore.Speak.Important.config` is missing.

Why is it missing? Because filename starts with a period '.', and we use TeamCity and Octopus Deploy / OctoPack to generate a NuGet package for deploying.

This is by-design behaviour by OctoPack - i.e. to not include files with leading periods in output packages (see [here](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/10807-octopack-2026-excludes-folders-starting-with)). But as comments state, there is now an option to allow for dot-files to deploy:

In your build-build step in TeamCity (runner type *MsBuild* or *Visual Studio (sln)*), in the field **Command line parameters**, insert or append the following:

`/p:OctoPackNuGetArguments=-NoDefaultExcludes`

Who the heck names files with a leading period anyway...